# Add an anchor to scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

Is it possible to add an anchor to this script?  Instead of scrolling all the way to the top, I would like to scroll to a particular anchor in the page.

Here is the current script:

```
if (isError) {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 700
}, 2500);
$("#error-div").show();
} else {
$("#error-div").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not really the need to include a huge plugin for this simple task.

With jQuerys `position()` - function ([jQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/position/)) you can get the position of an element in the DOM (as long as it's visible). It returns an object with a `top` and `left` - value, *relative* to the parent. If you want values relative to the document, use the `offset()` - function, usage stays the same.

I created a little fiddle to show you the basic usage:

http://jsfiddle.net/DtADS/

Answer (score 0):

Use the scrollto plugin, you can scroll the entire page to any element, or even scroll inside of elements.  http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you need to place something like that on the place in your page you want to scroll `<div id="scrollHere"></div>` and in your jquery:

```
window.location.href = "#scrollHere";
```

this method goes the page right where the #scrollHere rest, if that the case.